# Replace \n with <br> is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

**In my mongoDB:**

```
description: "Test\n\nTest"
```

When I try to show it in my ejs file the text ignores de "\n"

*Test Test*

**My HTML**

```
<div id="description">
    <%= test.description %>
</div>
```

I tried to fix this using this **code**:

```
var desc = $('#description').text();
desc.replace("\n", "<br>");

$('.description').text(desc);
```

**Also tried:**

```
desc.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

**and:**

```
desc.split("\n").join("<br />");
```

None of this worked

If I print `var desc = $('#description').text();` in the Chrome console, it shows this:

```
              Test

Test
```

What I'm doing wrong and how do i fix this?

Comment: You need to set the *result* of the `replace()` call to something. Eg. `desc = desc.replace(...`

Comment: And maybe you should stop using _.text_ if you want to set _HTML_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `text()` as you want to change the HTML markup....`text()` will ignore the `<br>` tags

Also you are just replacing the value not updating it.....need to put the replaced value in the `desc` variable by

```
desc = desc.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

Also `desc.replace("\n", "<br>");` will just replace the first `\n` match

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var desc = "Test\n\nTest"
desc = desc.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
$('#description').html(desc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, `desc.split("\n").join("<br />");` works fine for me.

```js
var desc = $('#description').text();
console.log("original text = " + desc);

desc = desc.split("\n").join("<br />");
console.log("using split/join = " + desc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description">
  Here is
  the contents of
  the div
  with line breaks in it.
</div>
```